# Does smoothing of Bayes classifier will increase precision?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayes

I have implemented Bayes multinominal and Bernoulli's model and my question is does the smoothing have any impact of the performance of both models (Laplace’s law of succession
or add one smoothing)?

Comment: why it shouldn't have? it's very simple, smoothing (or adding some prior pseudo-count) makes the decision a bit more conservative. The question is how you're going to choose the smoothing value, which in that case it can possibly lead to a better or worse performance comparing to the other values

Comment: hope it was helpful! maybe taking a look at this paper would help to understand the subject deeper
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/minka-multinomial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, smoothing will influence the model because it will tend to make the model's decisions more conservative (or, in Bayesian terms, the posterior predictive distribution will be pulled toward the prior implied by the smoothing). What this means in terms of "performance" of a model depends on how you define "performance" -- what problem are you trying to solve?